# Calling phone number directly from QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, hyperlink

I would like to call a phone number from QGIS using the installed CTI program. The phone number is stored in the feature attributes. My intention is to open the CTI program after using the identify / select features function or using an action on the layer.

E-mail addresses are automatically displayed as hyperlinks in QGIS in the identify / select features function. When clicking on the E-Mail-Adress, my mail program opens. I would like to achieve the same for phone numbers.

I have already tried to create a virtual field containing a hyperlink e.g. `<a href="tel:+99 99 999 99">+99 99 999 99</a>`. The same i tried in the action settings with `open [% "phonenumber" %]`

Comment: Have a look at actions: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html?

Comment: If your CTI program can call a phone number by command `my_CTI.exe "+99 99 999 99"`, so you can set up the action : `"C:/folder/my_CTI.exe" [% "phonenumber" %]` as `generic`.

Answer (score 8):

Using the suggestion of @J.Monticolo from comments, this worked together with my CTI program.

In the actions dialog you just need to set the following code:

```
"C:/folder/my_CTI.exe" [% "phonenumber" %]
```

[image: Example of action to call phone number]